# python eval in "library" file

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I've got a file, we'll call him **test1.py** that contains:

```
code='''
class Something(object):
  def __init__(self):
    print "blah blah blah, this is a horrible idea"
def run():
  print "don't preach at me you pretentious fool"
'''
eval(compile(code, '<string>', 'exec'))
```

then below my `eval` statement, in that same **test1.py** file I can of course do stuff like:

```
x = Something()
run()
```

BUT... what if say I've got another file called **test2.py** and I want to be able to run `run()` or instantiate a `Something` from there after firing an `import test1`?  I'm assuming there is some manipulation of `locals()` or `globals()` necessary but the Googles are failing me here.

Comment: Don't feel too bad; `collections.namedtuple` in the standard library uses `exec` to execute a class definition built from a textual template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I do not think you need to do any kind of `locals()` or `globals()` manipulation, you can just do - `import test1` , and then instantiate `Something` object as -

```
import test1
x = test1.Something()
test1.run()
```

---

Example/Demo -

My `a.py` has exactly same code you pasted for `test1.py` , and then I can do -

```
>>> import a
>>> x = a.Something()
blah blah blah, this is a horrible idea
>>> a.run()
don't preach at me you pretentious fool
```

Also, you should listen to what the `__init__()` says, this is really a *horrible* idea.

Comment: Ah.. thanks so much!  YOU should listen to what the run() says.  ;-)

Comment: PS... just for posterities sake, I'm not actually using this in the wild.  It is indeed a horrible idea.